# Delete files from a folder based on an existing set of files in another folder

Tags: java, eclipse, file, duplicates, delete-file

This one I couldn't find a proper answer.

I have 2 folders. One is called 'src', where
my java source code is located. The other one
is called 'srcGenerated' and has a set of files
created by a code generator. srcGenerated is a
superset of src.

I want to use both folders as my build path on
Eclipse. The problem is the duplicated files in 
srcGenerated. Since there is no way to supress
the generation of files that are already in src,
my question is, how to delete the duplicated files
in srcGenerated based on the existing set of files
from src.

Ant or Powershell script preferred.

Answer (score 0):

May not be the easiest one, but this is what I though of.

You can exclude Java files from srcGenerated that you don't want to be included while building.

[image: Right click on project, Java Build Path]

Here you can exclude all the files that you don't want to be built. I know, it's painstaking if there are hundreds of conflicting Java files. But it definitely works.

[image: Set exclude pattern]

Comment: Hi adarshr,

Thanks for your reply.

Unfortunately we are talking about something like 500 files. :(
What´s worst, the number of generated files increases now and then.
For each new class in our UML model, something like 20 new files are added.
So it isn´t an option for me.

Rod